# What are the proper steps to be taken before a dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I want to transition into the world of Ubuntu, I dual booted Ubuntu once before and although I could run Ubuntu, The option to select either Windows or Ubuntu never appears when I restart the PC, it went directly to the Windows Boot Manager. I could access Ubuntu by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> for the start up menu, then manually select Ubuntu.

With this install I want to make sure this doesn't happen, Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT:My windows is installed in C drive which happens to be an SSD(128GB), I installed ubuntu on space which i partitioned from a 1TB hard drive,Also windows is installed in UEFI mode
The specs of my machine are as follows:

OS:Win 10 Home

System Model Name:HP-PAVILION Notebook

BIOS mode :UEFI

Processor:Intel Core i7-6700HQ@2.60GHz

Also Legacy support is enabled and secure boot is disabled , i CANNOT change the status of secure boot as it seems to be grayed out

Comment: What machine are you using?

Comment: And, did you install Ubuntu onto a different drive than Windows was installed on? Please click [edit] and add the reply to your question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: You may have installed Ubuntu in the Legacy BIOS mode while Windows was installed in UEFI mode. The key to dualbooting is to install both in the same mode. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525280/how-to-install-ubuntu-in-a-pre-installed-windows-8-1-64-bit-without-uefi/525287#525287) for more.

Comment: HP historically has not been good about booting "ubuntu" UEFI entry. But some recently have said UEFI update resolves many issues. Have you updated UEFI to most current version? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

You should provide details on the actual specs of your computer.
As @K7AAY mentioned, you need at least two different drives.
Most OS boot loaders are stored in the MBR by default, which is kind of a space in a storage drive, so if you install first Ubuntu (using the default settings) and then Windows, Windows overwrites Ubuntu's boot system. If you install first Windows and then Ubuntu, Ubuntu could overwrite Windows' boot system, or, at least be unreachable without modifying the boot order settings in your UEFI settings.

So, if you have two different drives, you don't have to worry about any of this. At most, you would only need to set a default HDD to boot from in your UEFI settings, and I recommend setting Ubuntu's as default, since it's possible to boot Windows using grub, but not the other way around (again, speaking about defaults).

In other words, let's say you already have two physical storage drives, like a Samsung SSD and a Seagate HDD.
You'd install Windows in the Seagate drive and Ubuntu in the Samsung one.
At this point, Ubuntu should recognize you've already installed Windows in your computer, adding it as a boot option to grub.
Then, finally, you would have to go to UEFI/BIOS and look for the boot order settings, setting the Samsung drive as the first option and you're good to go.

Comment: You don't actually need 2 different drives but it's a better idea to have that arrangement anyway.

Comment: I'm aware, but the OP said they're getting started into the Linux world, so I explained what has worked for me in the least amount of time and steps.